# sqlconnector getting query preparation errors when connecting to openquery

Tags: c#, linked-server

I've got a code as shown below. When I try to use it without any Parameters it works and I get a result from the SQL Statement, bt as soon as I try to use Parameters......c# shouts our: "An error occurred while preparing the query......for execution against OLE DB Provider".

As Info here: I'm using a linked Server on an SQL Server to communicate with a db2 Server.

For the code prepareDb2Statement does nothing more than put the openquery around it.  NamedParameter is "just" a value and Name class.

```
    public DataTable Execute(string executeString, List<NamedParameter> parameterList)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        string preparedExecuteString = this.PrepareDb2Statement(executeString);

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter databaseDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(preparedExecuteString, databaseConnection))
                {
                    if (parameterList != null && parameterList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (NamedParameter parameter in parameterList)
                        {
                            databaseDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    databaseDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = _CommandTimeout;
                    databaseDataAdapter.Fill(data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Example execution:

```
        List<NamedParameter> _list = new List<NamedParameter>
        {
            new NamedParameter("@client", cli),
            new NamedParameter("@account", acc)
        };

        this.Execute("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE Client=@client AND account=@account");
```

The preparedExecutestring is: `select * from openquery(mylinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM sales WHERE Client=@client AND account=@account')`

As mentioned, when I try the SQL without any Parameters it works as intended. With the Parameters I get the error. Now I know openquery itself when run from within an SQL Server does not like Parameters, but that shouldn't affect this as the sqlconnector replaces them before he executes the SQL.

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not that `OPENQUERY` doesn't "like" parameters, it simply does not support them at all. If you really have code that replaces the parameters by literals somehow (it's not clear that's the case from just the code you posted), that code has to take care of escaping string literals properly (doubling up single quotes), since within `OPENQUERY` the entire query is one string literal. Note that `SqlCommand` does *not* do any kind of parameter replacing -- it properly passes the parameters *as parameters*, something which will not work with parameters buried in the string of `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok then I have probably misinterpreted how the sql commands in c# work. Always thought they replaced the parameters BEFORE sending the query to sql  not that they just send them also as parameters. (I'm just using the normal code there to avoid sql injection, thus this kind of parameters I'm using).  So in essence my way there doesn't work at all because the parameters I used to avoid sql injection are really sent as parameters to the openquery query, correct so?

Comment: Yes. Parameters not only avoid SQL injection, they're passed as the correct type to avoid conversion issues (a `DateTime` will be passed as a time stamp value, not as some locale-formatted date/time string). They're part of the data protocol of SQL Server itself. Some data access libraries may "fake" parameters by doing string replacement, but not ADO.NET. (The complexity of passing values correctly is also what makes formatting the queries to the DB2 server potentially problematic. If possible, avoid this approach in favor of direct queries on views/synonyms.)

Comment: that means then I need to find a different way to avoid sql injections. sigh sometimes I really hate microsoft.  tnx for the clearification @JeroenMostert